# SonarQube in Azure DevOps Pipeline leads to error MSB6006: "csc.dll" exited with code 137

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube

We are trying to use the [SonarQube v5.5](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube) extension in our Azure DevOps pipelines. The build runs fine as long as we do not include the pipeline task **SonarQubePrepare** in our azure-pipelines.yml file. As soon as we include the mentioned task, the MSBuild seems to end in a loop with the error `error MSB6006: "csc.dll" exited with code 137` and then keeps trying to build the same project.

We did a little research and found that this could be related to a memory issue. We have allocated 16gb of ram to the build AgentPool. The only effect seems to be that the loop runs faster than before.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

**Pipeline:**

```
jobs:
    - job: 'BackendBuild'

    pool:
       name: 'xyz'

    workspace:
       clean: all

    steps:
       - checkout: git://$(repository) # Variable for repository name to checkout
         persistCredentials: true
         clean: true
       
       # Build runs fine without this task
       - task: SonarQubePrepare@5
         displayName: Prepare analysis with SonarQube (MSBuild)
         inputs:
            SonarQube: 'Sonarqube' # Service connection name
            scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
            projectKey: $(repository)
            projectName: $(repository)

       - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: 'Build projects'
            inputs:
               projects: '**/*.csproj'
               arguments: '--configuration Release'
```

**Log:**

> ##[warning]myproj.Domain.Email/Services/ViewRenderingService.cs(31,35): Warning S4457: Split this method into two, one handling parameters
> check and the other handling the asynchronous code.
> Services/ViewRenderingService.cs(31,35): warning S4457: Split this
> method into two, one handling parameters check and the other handling
> the asynchronous code.
> [/azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.Domain.Email/myproj.Domain.Email.csproj]
> Sonar: (myproj.Domain.Email.csproj) Project processed successfully
> Sonar: Preparing for Razor compilation, moved files
> (/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/Issues.json;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/encoding.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/file-metadata.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/metrics.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/symrefs.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/token-cpd.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/token-type.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/ProjectInfo.xml) to /azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp.   Sonar: After Razor
> compilation, moved files
> (/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/Issues.Views.json;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9/output-cs/file-metadata.pb)
> to /azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.Razor.   Sonar: After Razor
> compilation, moved files
> (/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/Issues.json;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/encoding.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/file-metadata.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/metrics.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/symrefs.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/token-cpd.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/output-cs/token-type.pb;/azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9.tmp/ProjectInfo.xml)
> to /azp/agent/_work/1/.sonarqube/out/9 and will remove the temporary
> folder.
> ##[error]/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.420/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5): **Error MSB6006: "csc.dll" exited with code 137.**
> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.420/Roslyn/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(70,5):
> error MSB6006: "csc.dll" exited with code 137.
> [/azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.Data/myproj.Data.csproj]
> myproj.Domain.Messages ->
> /azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.Domain.Messages/bin/Release/netstandard2.1/myproj.Domain.Messages.dll
> myproj.Domain.Email ->
> /azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.Domain.Email/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/myproj.Domain.Email.dll
> Sonar: (myproj.Domain.Messages.csproj) Project processed successfully
> myproj.Domain.Email ->
> /azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.Domain.Email/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/myproj.Domain.Email.Views.dll
> myproj.backoffice.sts ->
> /azp/agent/_work/1/s/myproj.backoffice.sts/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/myproj.backoffice.sts.dll
> Sonar: (myproj.backoffice.sts.csproj) Project processed successfully
>
> Build FAILED.

Comment: I asked now the same question on the official SonarSouce Community platfform: 
https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-in-azure-devops-pipeline-leads-to-error-msb6006-csc-dll-exited-with-code-137/66928